# Publish React Component to NPM - transpile with Babel necessary?

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

currently we transpile our components with Babel (@babel/env, @babel/preset-react) before uploading to NPM. This will convert any .jsx file to a .js. So far so good.

But the question arises as to whether this is necessary at all, since we are only adding the React components to one project anyway.

Doesn't it make sense to transpile the components that are uploaded to NPM without Babel because this will be done in the project anyway?

Comment: IIRC webpack won't automatically transpile artifacts in node_modules unless configured to do so, but I'm not sure what the latest version(s) do. Ideally npm artifacts will run out-of-the-box with no additional configuration.